# Dificuldades para mostrar as teclas de uma calculadora em um input

Tags: javascript, html, input, onclick

1 - ESTRUTURA DO INPUT :

```
<section class="screen">
  <form name="calc">
    <input type="text" class="internal-screen-result" name="text" readonly id="screenResult">
  </form>
</section>
```

2 - Exemplo de tecla da calculadora com onclick que enviará o valor para a função :

```
<button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys('7')">7</button>
```

3 - Esta seria a função para mostrar os inputs :

```
getAndShowKeys = (key) => {
    document.querySelector('#screenResult').innerHTML = key;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o objetivo for ao clicar no botão inserir num input o seu valor:

Código do botão:

```
<button class="num" onclick="getAndShowKeys(this)" value="7">7</button>
```

Função:

```
function getAndShowKeys(button){
        document.getElementById('screenResult').value = button.value;
    }
```